# if statement, Code not work

Tags: android, string, button, if-statement, android-edittext

```
final EditText yaz = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    final Button bas = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

    yaz.setText("500");
        bas.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(View v) {
                                            String afd = yaz.getText().toString();
                                            if (afd == "1000") {
                                                yaz.setText("2000");
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
    );
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
if (afd == "1000")
```

with

```
if (afd.equals("1000"))
```

This should work.

The idea is that `==` checks values of entities that lie on the stack, and in Java, only primitive types and references are held on the stack. Objects lie on the heap, and to compare object state you need a runtime virtual method like `equals()` (and not an operator like `==`).

Answer (score 4):

In Java, you cannot check equality between `Strings` with the `==` operator. This operator checks equal references for reference types, and equal values for primitive types only. Since `String` is a reference type, there's no surprise this is failing.

To check equality between `Strings` (or `Objects` for that matter), use this:

```
str1.equals(str2);
```

or in your case:

```
afd.equals("1000");
```

Comment: thank you very much, good work